# pytest says fixture not found while i call this

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm calling the following code using pytest.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def driver_init(request):
        ch_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=Data.Ch_exe_path)
        request.cls.driver = ch_driver
        yield
        ch_driver.close()
    
    
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_init")
```

**I'm getting an error saying**

fixture 'driver_init' not found. available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, extra, metadata, monkeypatch, pytestcon
fig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, testrun_uid, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
, worker_id.

Comment: Looks ok to me - can you show the test class after the decorator? Is there more code that uses the fixture?

Answer (score 0):

It is Working when I change the function name to "setup" instead of "driver_init".